# Is it possible to dynamically change the height of the InputAccessoryView?

Tags: react-native

React Native version 0.55 ships with a [InputAccessoryView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/inputaccessoryview.html).  Is it possible to dynamically change the height of that InputAccessoryView?

In the example below I set the initial height to 50 via  `this.state.height`. When I press the button, I update  `this.state.height` to 200, however the height change does not get rendered (btw. `this.state.backgroundColor` change gets correctly rendered).

Another use case for this would be to change the height whenever a sticky `<TextInput>` wrapped in a `<InputAccessoryView>` of a chat app extends over multiple lines.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  View,
  TextInput,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  ScrollView
} from "react-native";
const Button = require("Button");
const InputAccessoryView = require("InputAccessoryView");
const inputAccessoryViewID = "inputAccessoryView1";
const Dimensions = require("Dimensions");

class Demo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: "yellow"
  };

  render() {
    const { width } = Dimensions.get("window");
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "blue",
          flex: 1,
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center"
        }}
        behavior="position"
      >
        <ScrollView
          keyboardDismissMode="interactive"
          contentContainerStyle={{
            flex: 1,
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "center"
          }}
        >
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Email"
            style={{
              height: 50,
              backgroundColor: "white",
              width: width - 30
            }}
            inputAccessoryViewID={inputAccessoryViewID}
          />
        </ScrollView>
        <InputAccessoryView nativeID={inputAccessoryViewID}>
          <View
            style={{
              backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor,
              width,
              height: this.state.height
            }}
          >
            <Button
              onPress={() =>
                this.setState({
                  height: 200,
                  backgroundColor: "red"
                })
              }
              title="Change Input Style"
            />
          </View>
        </InputAccessoryView>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}

export default Demo;
```